# How to add Playwright junit reporter custom xray properties

Tags: junit, playwright

https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Taking+advantage+of+JUnit+XML+reports

Is there any way to use Junit reporter in playwright with extended xray properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this - [Playwright JUnit reporter](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#junit-reporter) has only two params, `outputFile` and `stripANSIControlSequences`.

The only option for this is to create your own JUnit reporter based on https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/main/packages/playwright/src/reporters/junit.ts#L25. For example - using [Custom Annotations](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#custom-annotations).